# Evaluating text field while being typed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to write a little HTML/JavaScript code that will analyze a password field to make sure it has the required characters while being typed. [Here's a JSFiddle for a visual reference](http://jsfiddle.net/wQny9/).

What I want to happen is that when a required character is typed into the password field, the corresponding text turns green.  But when I type in the field, the text stays red.  I can't seem to find what I did wrong.  Is there something wrong with my JavaScript?

And here's my code in one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>hw5</title>
    <style>
        p {
            color:red;
            position:absolute;
            left:250px;
            top:95px;
            text-align:right
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HW5</h1>


    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input style="margin-left:2px" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    <br/>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input style="margin-left:6px" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <br/>


    <p id="lower">must have one lower</p>
    <p style="top:115px" id="upper">must have one upper</p>
    <p style="top:135px" id="number">must have one number</p>
    <p style="top:155px" id="punct">must have one punct</p>

    <script>
        var pass = document.getElementById('password');
        var upper = document.getElementById('upper');
        var lower = document.getElementById('lower');
        var number = document.getElementById('number');
        var punct = document.getElementById('punct');

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#password').keyup(checkPassword);
        });

        function checkPassword() {
            var pass = $('#password').val();


            if (pass.search(/[A-Z]/)) {
                upper.style.color = "green";
            } else upper.style.color = "red";

            if (pass.search(/[a-z]/)) {
                lower.style.color = "green";
            } else lower.style.color = "red";

            if (pass.search(/\d/)) {
                number.style.color = "green";
            } else number.style.color = "red";

            if (pass.search(/[!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]/)) {
                punct.style.color = "green";
            } else punct.style.color = "red";
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @cookiemonster sorry, realized I left the major part out. I've edited it in.

Comment: @bjb568: There's already a Fiddle in the OP.  I don't think the `checkPassword` function is executing.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're invoking the `checkPassword` function instead of passing it. `$('#password').keyup(checkPassword());` Drop the `()`.

Comment: ...the other part is that `.search()` returns a 0-based index. If none was found, it will return `-1`, which is a truthy value. http://jsfiddle.net/wQny9/1/

Comment: @cookiemonster Thanks! Although, it doesn't seem to work when I changed that in my file and opened it in my browser.

Comment: In your jsFiddle you didn't have jQuery loaded. Make sure it's loaded in your actual file. Otherwise no, there's no way for us to know what's wrong in your file without seeing it.

Comment: @cookiemonster Got it. I guess I didn't understand JQuery at all. It works now though after I looked around some more. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, it's just a library of pre-written JavaScript code. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's search function returns the position, not TRUE or FALSE.

That means that **your comparison fails when the characters found in the 0 position**...

Also, change the event handling since yours won't work.

This should work (have not tested the RegExp thoroughly though).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#password').keyup(function() {

       var pass = $('#password').val();

       if (pass.search(/[A-Z]/) != -1) {
            upper.style.color = "green";
        } else upper.style.color = "red";

        if (pass.search(/[a-z]/) != -1) {
            lower.style.color = "green";
        } else lower.style.color = "red";

        if (pass.search(/\d/) != -1) {
            number.style.color = "green";
        } else number.style.color = "red";

        if (pass.search(/[!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]/) != -1) {
            punct.style.color = "green";
        } else punct.style.color = "red";

    });
});
```

Also, if you want a cleaner code, you could use:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#password').keyup(function() {

           var pass = $('#password').val();  

           upper.style.color = (pass.search(/[A-Z]/) != -1) ? 'green' : 'red';
           lower.style.color = (pass.search(/[a-z]/) != -1) ? 'green' : 'red';
           number.style.color = (pass.search(/\d/) != -1) ? 'green' : 'red';
           punct.style.color = (pass.search(/[!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]/) != -1) ? 'green' : 'red';

        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnH7J/1/)

Hope this helps.